# How to hide current candle or make it transparent?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to not display the current candle.

My idea is:

```
barcolor(barstate.isrealtime? #transparent? : na)
```

But the problem is there's no transparent color or transp property in barcolor. Furthermore, the wick will still show.

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts on using plotcandle

Have a look at this script
https://uk.tradingview.com/script/GcHvlBtX-Plot-any-scrip-symbol/

Have a read here (wickcolor)

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/annotations/Custom_OHLC_bars_and_candles.html

Apologies I am not at my laptop to code it.